# Drupal dynamic Taxonomy term values

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, custom-taxonomy

I'm new to Drupal, and somehow miss a feature. (or I guess just don't know how to activate it)
Let's say I have a content type which is using the term reference (taxonomy field type)
Is it possible to have it filled dynamically (e.g. with already existing content from my site?

I don't want to type in all possible Tag/Term options, but instead want some kind of dynamic category choice for an author, e.g. feeded by existing content (articles/pages) from the drupal site itself.

Is there a certain module I need or how is it done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add to your nodes a reference to another node in your site you need to use a node reference field and not a term reference. To be able to add that kind of field to your content type, you need to install [References module](https://drupal.org/project/references), and probably [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) to show pages that leverage your references. If you provide some details of your requirements I can be more specific.